# Progress Bar working with Fit Api

Tags: java, android, api

I'm trying to make a step counter using the fitness api, i got it to count my steps and i connected the app to google services. Now i'm trying to make a progress bar for my app but i don't know how to make it work with the value form the fitness api this is the code i wrote so far. Sorry i put this question 2x (i searched before).

```
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnDataPointListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


private static final int REQUEST_OAUTH = 1;
private static final String AUTH_PENDING = "auth_state_pending";
private boolean authInProgress = false;
private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private Value progressStatus = 0;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private  TextView textView;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        authInProgress = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(AUTH_PENDING);
    }

    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();


}
@Override
protected void onStart(){
    progressStatus = 0;
    super.onStart();
    mApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    DataSourcesRequest dataSourceRequest = new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
            .setDataTypes( DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE )
            .setDataSourceTypes( DataSource.TYPE_RAW )
            .build();

    ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult> dataSourcesResultCallback = new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
            for( DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources() ) {
                if( DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE.equals( dataSource.getDataType() ) ) {
                    registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mApiClient, dataSourceRequest)
            .setResultCallback(dataSourcesResultCallback);
}
private void registerFitnessDataListener(DataSource dataSource, DataType dataType) {

    SensorRequest request = new SensorRequest.Builder()
            .setDataSource( dataSource )
            .setDataType( dataType )
            .setSamplingRate( 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS )
            .build();

    Fitness.SensorsApi.add( mApiClient, request, this )
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.e( "GoogleFit", "SensorApi successfully added" );
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if(!authInProgress){
        try{
            authInProgress = true;
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult( MainActivity.this,REQUEST_OAUTH);
        }  catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e){}

    }else {
        Log.e( "GoogleFit" , "authInProgress" );
    }


}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if( requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH ) {
        authInProgress = false;
        if( resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
            if( !mApiClient.isConnecting() && !mApiClient.isConnected() ) {
                mApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else if( resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED ) {
            Log.e( "GoogleFit", "RESULT_CANCELED" );
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("GoogleFit", "requestCode NOT request_oauth");
    }
}
@Override
public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
    for( final Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields() ) {
        final Value value = dataPoint.getValue( field );
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field: " + field.getName() + " Value: " + value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (progressStatus){
                    progressStatus = value;
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                                progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                                textView.setText("Progress:"+progressStatus+"/"+progressBar.getMax());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    try{Thread.sleep(100);}
                    catch (InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }




}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    Fitness.SensorsApi.remove( mApiClient, this )
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        mApiClient.disconnect();
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(AUTH_PENDING, authInProgress);
}
```

}

`

Comment: What's wrong with `progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus)`?

Comment: setProgress in ProgressBar can not be applied to (com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Value)

Comment: If that's an error, then so is `while (progressStatus)`...

Comment: Yes, and any other code related to progress bar, is there any other method to make this work?

Comment: It would be clearer what your problems were if you included the actual errors in your question. Please [edit] accordingly

Comment: If you just read the API, there is a `asFloat()` method to that `Value` class. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/Value

Comment: thx for the advice, i made some changes to tha code as following (got rid of the whil instace and the thread)
progressStatus = value.asInt();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
                                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                                    }
                                });

Comment: So is it working? If not, please [edit] your question with the errors you are getting

Comment: it's working now without an error, i will post below the full code, the only error i was getting is this one (setProgress in ProgressBar can not be applied to (com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Value) ) but setting the progress status to value.asInt(); did the trick.

Comment: I have only one question and i hope i don;t corss the line. Is there any method to reset the value over night ? Now it just counts steps until i will reset the device.

Comment: You could use `SharedPreferences` to store the present day. If you load the app on a future date, then you reset.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnDataPointListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


private static final int REQUEST_OAUTH = 1;
private static final String AUTH_PENDING = "auth_state_pending";
private boolean authInProgress = false;
private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private int progressStatus=0;
private Handler handler= new Handler();
private  TextView textView;
private Button toastButton;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        authInProgress = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(AUTH_PENDING);
    }

    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    toastButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_toast);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);


}
@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    mApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    DataSourcesRequest dataSourceRequest = new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
            .setDataTypes( DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE )
            .setDataSourceTypes( DataSource.TYPE_RAW )
            .build();

    ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult> dataSourcesResultCallback = new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
            for( DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources() ) {
                if( DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE.equals( dataSource.getDataType() ) ) {
                    registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mApiClient, dataSourceRequest)
            .setResultCallback(dataSourcesResultCallback);
}
private void registerFitnessDataListener(DataSource dataSource, DataType dataType) {

    SensorRequest request = new SensorRequest.Builder()
            .setDataSource( dataSource )
            .setDataType( dataType )
            .setSamplingRate( 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS )
            .build();

    Fitness.SensorsApi.add( mApiClient, request, this )
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.e( "GoogleFit", "SensorApi successfully added" );
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if(!authInProgress){
        try{
            authInProgress = true;
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult( MainActivity.this,REQUEST_OAUTH);
        }  catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e){}

    }else {
        Log.e( "GoogleFit" , "authInProgress" );
    }


}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if( requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH ) {
        authInProgress = false;
        if( resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
            if( !mApiClient.isConnecting() && !mApiClient.isConnected() ) {
                mApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else if( resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED ) {
            Log.e( "GoogleFit", "RESULT_CANCELED" );
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("GoogleFit", "requestCode NOT request_oauth");
    }
}
@Override
public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
    for( final Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields() ) {
        final Value value = dataPoint.getValue( field );
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                textView.setText(field.getName()+ ": " + value);
                textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                progressStatus = value.asInt();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                                }
                            });
            }
        });

        toastButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field: " + field.getName() + " Value: " + value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }
}










@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    Fitness.SensorsApi.remove( mApiClient, this )
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        mApiClient.disconnect();
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(AUTH_PENDING, authInProgress);
   }
}
```

This is the working code